# Cloudinary error: "please access via api-eu.cloudinary.com"

Tags: python, python-3.x, cloudinary

When I try to upload an image via Python to Cloudinary as such:

```
import cloudinary.uploader

cloudinary.config(
  cloud_name = 'our-name-eu',
  api_key = '…',
  api_secret = '…',
  private_cdn = True,
  secure_distribution = 'our-name-eu-res.cloudinary.com'
)
cloudinary.uploader.upload("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2fb-g_V-UT4/hqdefault.jpg")
```

Then I get the following error:

`Error: Cloud our-name-eu belongs to eu geo, please access via api-eu.cloudinary.com`

While [I see in the docs of the API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#uploading_with_a_direct_call_to_the_api) that the API URL is structured like `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloud name>/<resource_type>/upload` I assume I could replace `api` by `api-eu` but I don't see how I can specify this in the Python module.

I'm using Python 3.7.2 and the `cloudinary` package from `pip`.

Comment: Looks like it's the `upload_prefix`: https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/038837d42bcac24c9d2340de8ab8b7bbdf856354/cloudinary/utils.py#L700-L701

Comment: @jonrsharpe that was it! Do you want to write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/038837d42bcac24c9d2340de8ab8b7bbdf856354/cloudinary/utils.py#L700-L701):

```
def cloudinary_api_url(action='upload', **options):
    cloudinary_prefix = options.get("upload_prefix", cloudinary.config().upload_prefix)\
                        or "https://api.cloudinary.com"
    cloud_name = options.get("cloud_name", cloudinary.config().cloud_name)
    if not cloud_name:
        raise ValueError("Must supply cloud_name")
    resource_type = options.get("resource_type", "image")

    return encode_unicode_url("/".join([cloudinary_prefix, "v1_1", cloud_name, resource_type, action]))
```

it seems that the relevant configuration key is `upload_prefix`.

For reference, I found this by searching for the default value in the Python files in their repo: https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/search?l=Python&q=api.cloudinary.com.